# Как вывести адрес картинок на отдельный домен?

Tags: nginx

в коде сайта прописано, что картинка находится в папке /images/ (например `<a href="/images/img.png"></a>`)

адрес изображения на сайте выглядит http://site.com/images/img.png
как с помощью nginx сделать что бы на сайте изображение ссылалось по адресу http://img.site.com/img.com или http://img.site.com/images/img.com (главное, что бы изображения были на домене 3 уровня)

Comment: Пишите в коде страниц полный путь к картинкам.

Comment: к сожалению это не возможно. необходимо именно средствами  nginx'a реализовать

Comment: Ну тогда никак. Nginx не может поменять вашу страничку

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение

```
location ~* \.png$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://img.site.com$1 last;
}
```

Comment: И что это дало?